# Why replacing static files on Bluemix Cloud Foundry takes a long time?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, web-deployment, static-files

It takes me so much time (> 30mins) to replace the template code. The target file is 34M, so what could the problem be?

[image: upload failure]

[image: Command Line Capture]

Comment: Usually it is a matter of seconds or minutes, depending on network, complexity of updates, etc. There were some login issues reported here for your Bluemix region https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status
Did you retry?
In general, this is not really a programming question for SO, but something for the Bluemix support.

Comment: You updated the question with a new screenshot that shows that you are uploading 1 GB. Is that correct?

Comment: In general you don't want to upload the node_modules directory. The buildpack will run `npm install` for you and those downloads will be faster than your upload.

Comment: @data_henrik it's not right, actually the file is about 34M.

Comment: @opiethehokie it's weird, actually there's no node_modules directory in the folder.

Comment: It looks like you are uploading your Desktop `Uploading app files from: C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop`. You can try to cd into your application and do a cf push from there.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Thanks